# New React Context API + LocalStorage + Subscribe (Replacement for Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, state, react-context

I have an app using Redux. Is stores the global state as shown below:

Create Store:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const configureStore = initialState => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
};

export default configureStore;
```

Handles Local Storage

```
  const storageName = 'xxxState';
  export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem(storageName);
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch(err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = state => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem(storageName, serializedState);
  } catch(err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Finaly starts the app session:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Start from './start';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import { loadState, saveState } from './store/localStorage';
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

const persistedState = loadState();

const store = configureStore(persistedState);
store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
}, 1000));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Start />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

It works perfectly. So my question is: Is there any possibility to do the same with the new React Context API?

I am pretty confortable using the new context, I just want to know about store, localstorage, subscribe. So the the state is persisted even when the user leaves the app.

Answer (score 4):

store.js

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";

export const createStore = store => {
  const Context = createContext();
  let self;
  const setState = (action, state, args) => {
    self.setState(state);
  };
  const actions = Object.keys(store.actions).reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => {
      return {
        ...accumulator,
        [currentValue]: function(...args) {
          let result = store.actions[currentValue](
            { state: self.state, actions: self.value.actions },
            ...args
          );
          if (result) {
            result.then
              ? result.then(result => setState(currentValue, result, args))
              : setState(currentValue, result, args);
          }
        }
      };
    },
    {}
  );
  class Provider extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = store.initialState;
      self = this;
      this.value = {
        actions,
        state: this.state
      };
    }
    render() {
      if (this.state !== this.value.state) {
        this.value = {
          actions,
          state: this.state
        };
      }
      return (
        <Context.Provider value={this.value}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
      );
    }
  }
  class Consumer extends Component {
    renderProps = ({ actions, state }) => {
      // const { mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps } = this.props;
      return this.props.children({
        state: state,
        actions: actions
      });
    };
    render() {
      return <Context.Consumer>{this.renderProps}</Context.Consumer>;
    }
  }
  const connect = (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) => WrappedComponent => {
    return (
      <Consumer
        mapStateToProps={mapStateToProps}
        mapDispatchToProps={mapDispatchToProps}
      >
        {injectedProps => (
          <WrappedComponent {...injectedProps} {...this.props} />
        )}
      </Consumer>
    );
  };
  return {
    Provider,
    Consumer,
    connect
  };
};
```

Then for individual pages you can have actions and initial store value like this

```
import { createStore } from "@src/store";
import { Actions } from "../actions";
import { storage } from "@helpers/storage";
import constants from "@src/constants";

import { util } from "@src/utils";

function getInitialState() {
  let Id = null;
  if (storage.get(constants.STORAGE_KEY)) {
    let storageObject = storage.get(constants.STORAGE_KEY);
    Id = storageObject["Id"];
    selectedDate = storageObject["selectedDate"];
  }
  return {
    data: null,
    activeTab: "score",
    Id: Id
  };
}
const store = {
  initialState: getInitialState(),
  actions: Actions
};

export const { Provider, Consumer } = createStore(store);
```

Finally in your pages/HomePage/index.js
you can have
import { Provider } from './store';

```
render() {
  return (
    <Provider>
     <Homepage user={user} children={children} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

and in your pages/HomePage/Homepage.js
you can have

```
render() {
      return (
        <Consumer>
          {({ state, actions }) => {
            return this.renderChildrens(state, actions);
          }}
        </Consumer>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**First things first**

- Redux has nothing to do with `react` in specific, it is a state manager.
  it helps you manage a big JavaScript object that holds the state of your application.
- react's Context API is not even a new feature in react, it was there the whole time and it just got a new face. It's a way to pass down data to children without [prop drilling](https://blog.kentcdodds.com/prop-drilling-bb62e02cb691).

I think you are referring to `react-redux`.
`react-redux` is an abstraction, a way to bind your Redux store to react.
It's doing all the store subscription for you and help you create a `Container` and consumers using the `connect` HOC and the `Provider` component.
It also helps with passing down the store object (via the context API under the hood).

If you are using `Redux` already, i don't see any point for not using `react-redux`.

You can read in more details about the differences [In this post](https://medium.com/@sagiv.bengiat/redux-is-dead-long-live-reacts-context-api-d0180f4278da) (full disclosure, I'm the author).